# SQLAlchemy ORM session add only adding last value from dictionary instead of both

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

Howdie do,

I have a list that contains a dictionary such as:

```
[
    {71: flNEMjANX}, 
    {72: fl12nd1AD}
]
```

I'm adding the values using SQLAlchemy ORM session.add, but it's only adding the last entry to the database.

In fact, it's doing the same entry twice

How I'm calling this is:

```
for i in labels:
            for key in i:
                shipadd = connectdb.Ship(msn=key,label=i[key])
                connectdb.session.add(shipadd)
                connectdb.session.commit()
```

But when I check the database, I see the following

```
72 fl12nd1AD
72 fl12nd1AD
```

How do I make sure that the first item is added to the database as well as the last value?

It should look like this

```
71 flNEMjANX
72 fl12nd1AD
```

Comment: Is this really everything you do? Any code running after those loops?

Comment: Yes, this is all I'm doing. I have code that runs afterwards, however, it's not in relation to the storing of information in databases

Comment: Please enable logging of SQL statements generated by SQLAlchemy and see what they look like for this piece of code. You can do this by passing `verbose=True` to `create_engine(...)`.

Comment: Did you mix tabs and spaces for indentation? This could be an indentation problem.